# UIButton's target is fired before animation

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uibutton

I have programmed a Quiz in Xcode where I've created UIButtons programmatically displaying the answer to a question. When the user clicks the button the next question is loaded and the buttons position i shuffled to not make the right answer in the same place for each question (the right answer is however under the same UIButton for every question.)

This is how I create my buttons:

```
if (self.buttonRightAnswer == nil)
{
    self.buttonRightAnswer = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [self.buttonRightAnswer addTarget:self action:@selector(rightAnswer) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [self.view addSubview:self.buttonRightAnswer];
}

self.buttonRightAnswer.frame = CGRectMake(20.0, [[randomPositionArray objectAtIndex:0] floatValue], 280.0, 40.0);
[self.buttonRightAnswer setTitle:[[self.quiz.arrayWithQuestions objectAtIndex:questionNr - 1]valueForKey:@"RightAnswer"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

When the user clicks the right an answer the next question loads. Here it's a problem. The next question loads with the same method only shuffled positions and the animation of the press-down of the button is drawn after the buttons been moved resulting in the user seeing where the right answer is now.

How can I wait for the animation before moving the buttons?

I could solve this by having the buttons stay in one place, shuffling out the questions over the buttons and comparing the users answer with the right answer.. but this requires a hell of a lot more code.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use some of shit-code and insert some kind of 'sleep' before next shuffling buttons
2. Before you create the buttons againg (after a question was answered), you can add something  like (if you use differen images for button states)

   -(void)waitUntilButtonDeselected
   {
   bool selected = YES;
   while (selected)
   {
     bool selected = (self.buttonRightAnswer.currentBackgroundImage ==    UIImageOfNotSelectedButton);
   }
   }

The idea here is to check if the image of the button corresponds to not selected button.

Answer (score 0):

Typically when using a UIButton, events are triggered on `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`, or at the end of the touch.

You're triggering it on the touch down which is causing issues with the animation you want to happen.

It might be simpler for you to switch to using `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` instead of `UIControlEventTouchDown` since this should solve your problem and be more consistent with other iPhone apps.

Comment: You're right. It was a mistake to use UIControlEventDown. But UIControlEventTouchUpInside did not help me.. same effect still. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I solved it by setting a timer and pausing the execution until the animation has finished: timerToShowNextQuestion = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(rightAnswer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];